# Swapping variables in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning python3 and I came across the following line of code :

```
a = 1
b = 2
a,b = b,a
print(a) #prints 2
print(b) #prints 1
```

How is this line `a,b = b,a` working? Is Python automatically creating some temp variables? And what are the unseen possibilities? I mean, can I do the same for 3 or more variables in one line?

Comment: Yes, its indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

disassembling with [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
from dis import dis

def swap(a, b):
    a, b = b, a
    return a, b

dis(swap)
```

gives

```
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  8          13 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             19 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

where [`ROT_TWO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) means

> Swaps the two top-most stack items.

python does not need to create a temporary variable.

Comment: This is the same as arguing that C++ swap via temp variable does not require temp variable because the temp will be stored in a register, which is essentially what happens here.

Comment: @LiranFunaro no *python* variable is created, though. but i kind of agree...

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with multiple variables but it gets tricky:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> a, b, c = c, a, b
>>> c
2
>>> a
3
>>> b
1
>>>
```

This is useful when you want to update some values. For example, if new value of `y` needs to be incremented by `x`, and `x` takes the value of `y`:

```
x, y = y, y + x
```

Comment: No, Python does not create temporary variables. It is all done on the stack.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've deleted that part, didn't realize that. Thank you :)