# Does simultaneous assignment in Python happen actually simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, simultaneous

I came across a problem on Leetcode that asks to rotate an image 90 degree clockwise as shown below (image credit: Leetcode)

[image]

One of the solutions provided is as follows:

```
class Solution:
def rotate(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    self.transpose(matrix)
    self.reflect(matrix)

def transpose(self, matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            # Does the assignment here happen simultaneously?
            matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]

def reflect(self, matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n // 2):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[i][-j - 1] = matrix[i][-j - 1], matrix[i][j]
```

The solution is to first transpose the original matrix along the diagonal line and then reverse it along the X axis. That results in 90-degree clockwise rotation.

What I don't know is this -- I don't think this simultaneously assignment, `matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]`, will work without the assignment of `matrix[j][i]=matrix[i][j]` and `matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i]` happening at the same time. In other words, if `matrix[j][i]=matrix[i][j]` were to happen first, then the value in `matrix[j][i]` would have been changed/tainted before it is assigned to `matrix[i][j]`.

Could someone, who knows more about the behind-the-scene execution of simultaneous assignments, explain me why `matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]` is possible without using `temp` variable?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456/6273711) answers your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44518000/6328256

Comment: @JonathanCiapetti, joanis and Sash Sinha -- the SO posts you shared are very helpful. I learned something new about Python today! Thank you. :)

Comment: I edited the duplicate links to one that is more authoritative. For the duplicate closers: please try to avoid using duplicate targets that are themselves duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not simultaneous. But the right side is evaluated completely before any assignments take place.

It's essentially equivalent to:

```
temp = matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]
matrix[j][i] = temp[0]
matrix[i][j] = temp[1]
```

`temp` contains the values in the matrix cells, not references to the matrix cells. So reassigning the matrix elements has no effect on `temp`.

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new about Python today (that is, Python evaluates the right side of the expression first, and that it uses stack in assembly to swap them).